# New to android Development: Android Emulator always has apps crash

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-emulator, installation

I'm new to Android Development (please be kind), and I've tried setting up my dev environment on two separate machines, one with an AMD processor, and one with an Intel processor. On both machines, I am unable to open an app within the emulator. I've spent multiple hours searching for the problem, and now I need help.

Before I say anything more, I want to mention that eclipse wouldn't run on my machine until I installed the 32 bit JDK, even though I'm running a 64 bit machine that has the 64 bit jdk installed. (Could that have something to do with it?)

Please check my imgur link to follow what I'm doing. 
[Imgur Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjLUb.jpg)

Let me tell you guys what I'm doing, and you guys can tell me what I'm doing wrong.

In the Package Explorer, I right click, then go to New>Android Application Project.

I then change the Application name, Package name, and minimum required SDK.

I then click next until I reach the "Create Activity" menu, and check that the box next to "Create Activity," and select "Blank Activity."

I then click next, and then click finish.

I assume that this is enough that I should be able to run it in the emulator, so to test the emulator, I then select run configurations, and select my app, and select "com.johndavisdesign.helloworld.MainActivity.

I set my target to an AVD emulating a Nexus 10 running Android 4.4.

This launches the emulator, but will not install the program, no matter how long I wait. If I run configurations again without closing the emulator, the program will open, but will say "Unfortunately, HelloWorld has stopped."

My console reads:

```
[2014-07-09 13:34:35 - HelloWorld] ------------------------------
[2014-07-09 13:34:35 - HelloWorld] Android Launch!
[2014-07-09 13:34:35 - HelloWorld] adb is running normally.
[2014-07-09 13:34:35 - HelloWorld] Performing com.johndavisdesign.helloworld.MainActivity activity launch
[2014-07-09 13:34:35 - HelloWorld] Automatic Target Mode: Preferred AVD 'Test' is not available. Launching new emulator.
[2014-07-09 13:34:35 - HelloWorld] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'Test'
[2014-07-09 13:34:36 - Emulator] emulator: device fd:740
[2014-07-09 13:34:36 - Emulator] 
[2014-07-09 13:34:36 - Emulator] HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode
[2014-07-09 13:34:36 - Emulator] creating window 0 0 1640 1025
[2014-07-09 13:34:36 - Emulator] emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered
[2014-07-09 13:34:36 - Emulator] 
[2014-07-09 13:34:36 - HelloWorld] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2014-07-09 13:34:36 - HelloWorld] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2014-07-09 13:35:07 - HelloWorld] ------------------------------
[2014-07-09 13:35:07 - HelloWorld] Android Launch!
[2014-07-09 13:35:07 - HelloWorld] adb is running normally.
[2014-07-09 13:35:07 - HelloWorld] Performing com.johndavisdesign.helloworld.MainActivity activity launch
[2014-07-09 13:35:07 - HelloWorld] Automatic Target Mode: Preferred AVD 'Test' is available on emulator 'emulator-5554'
[2014-07-09 13:35:07 - HelloWorld] Uploading HelloWorld.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2014-07-09 13:35:08 - HelloWorld] Installing HelloWorld.apk...
[2014-07-09 13:35:08 - HelloWorld] Success!
[2014-07-09 13:35:08 - HelloWorld] Starting activity com.johndavisdesign.helloworld.MainActivity on device emulator-5554
[2014-07-09 13:35:08 - HelloWorld] ActivityManager: WARNING: linker: libdvm.so has text relocations. This is wasting memory and prevents security hardening. Please fix.
[2014-07-09 13:35:08 - HelloWorld] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.johndavisdesign.helloworld/.MainActivity }
[2014-07-09 13:35:21 - HelloWorld] HOME is up on device 'emulator-5554'
[2014-07-09 13:35:21 - HelloWorld] Application already deployed. No need to reinstall.
[2014-07-09 13:35:21 - HelloWorld] Starting activity com.johndavisdesign.helloworld.MainActivity on device emulator-5554
[2014-07-09 13:35:21 - HelloWorld] ActivityManager: WARNING: linker: libdvm.so has text relocations. This is wasting memory and prevents security hardening. Please fix.
[2014-07-09 13:35:21 - HelloWorld] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.johndavisdesign.helloworld/.MainActivity }
```

My logcat file reads:

```
07-09 17:35:06.550: D/AndroidRuntime(1582): Shutting down VM
07-09 17:35:06.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1582): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-09 17:35:06.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1582): Process: com.johndavisdesign.helloworld, PID: 1582
07-09 17:35:06.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1582): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.johndavisdesign.helloworld/com.johndavisdesign.helloworld.MainActivity}: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: You cannot combine swipe dismissal and the action bar.
07-09 17:35:06.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1582):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2197)
07-09 17:35:06.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1582):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2258)
07-09 17:35:06.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1582):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:138)
07-09 17:35:06.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1582):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1209)
07-09 17:35:06.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1582):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-09 17:35:06.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1582):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-09 17:35:06.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1582):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5026)
07-09 17:35:06.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1582):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-09 17:35:06.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1582):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-09 17:35:06.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1582):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
07-09 17:35:06.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1582):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
07-09 17:35:06.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1582):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-09 17:35:06.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1582): Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: You cannot combine swipe dismissal and the action bar.
07-09 17:35:06.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1582):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.requestFeature(PhoneWindow.java:275)
07-09 17:35:06.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1582):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2872)
07-09 17:35:06.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1582):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:3129)
07-09 17:35:06.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1582):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:303)
07-09 17:35:06.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1582):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1930)
07-09 17:35:06.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1582):     at com.johndavisdesign.helloworld.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:14)
07-09 17:35:06.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1582):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5242)
07-09 17:35:06.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1582):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
07-09 17:35:06.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1582):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2161)
07-09 17:35:06.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1582):     ... 11 more
07-09 17:35:06.550: W/dalvikvm(1582): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xacd27ce8)
07-09 17:40:06.574: I/Process(1582): Sending signal. PID: 1582 SIG: 9
07-09 17:40:06.614: D/AndroidRuntime(1637): Shutting down VM
07-09 17:40:06.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1637): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-09 17:40:06.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1637): Process: com.johndavisdesign.helloworld, PID: 1637
07-09 17:40:06.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1637): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.johndavisdesign.helloworld/com.johndavisdesign.helloworld.MainActivity}: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: You cannot combine swipe dismissal and the action bar.
07-09 17:40:06.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1637):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2197)
07-09 17:40:06.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1637):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2258)
07-09 17:40:06.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1637):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:138)
07-09 17:40:06.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1637):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1209)
07-09 17:40:06.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1637):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-09 17:40:06.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1637):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-09 17:40:06.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1637):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5026)
07-09 17:40:06.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1637):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-09 17:40:06.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1637):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-09 17:40:06.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1637):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
07-09 17:40:06.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1637):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
07-09 17:40:06.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1637):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-09 17:40:06.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1637): Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: You cannot combine swipe dismissal and the action bar.
07-09 17:40:06.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1637):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.requestFeature(PhoneWindow.java:275)
07-09 17:40:06.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1637):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2872)
07-09 17:40:06.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1637):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:3129)
07-09 17:40:06.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1637):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:303)
07-09 17:40:06.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1637):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1930)
07-09 17:40:06.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1637):     at com.johndavisdesign.helloworld.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:14)
07-09 17:40:06.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1637):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5242)
07-09 17:40:06.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1637):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
07-09 17:40:06.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1637):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2161)
07-09 17:40:06.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1637):     ... 11 more
07-09 17:40:06.614: W/dalvikvm(1637): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xacd27ce8)
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

Here is MainActivity.java:

```
package com.johndavisdesign.helloworld;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

EDIT 2:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.johndavisdesign.helloworld.MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What is at line 14 of MainActivity.onCreate() ?

Comment: I added MainActivity.java to the original post.

Comment: Post your activity_main.xml

Comment: I just posted it. Thanks for taking a look at my problem.

Comment: In the new project wizard, you specified that you want to compile with API20 Android 4.4 KitKat Wear.  Create a new project and compile with the normal API19 Android 4.4 KitKat.  It basically thinks you want to create an Android Wear project, which I'm assuming you don't.

Comment: Good catch. Unfortuantely, that hasn't solved the problem. Setting my Minimum Required SDK, my Target SDK, and my "Compile with" all to API19:Android 4.4 (KitKat) still prevents the application from launching properly.

Comment: Are you getting the same error in logcat?

Comment: YOU GUYS ARE THE BEST! After you noticed that I was making a wear project, I double checked the version of my AVD, which was also running an Android Wear OS. I would have never solved this without your help. THANKS!!!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are making an Android Wear project, do you really want that? Did you try to make a "normal" Android Project?

Comment: You're right. After changing the "compile with," and changing my AVD's OS, everything ran fine. Thanks for the help!